# How to read the cmd command response instruments -s devices in Java iOS

Tags: java, ios, exec, appium-ios

How to read the cmd command response using Java?

```
String[] str = { "instruments -s devices" };
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(str);
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line = "";
String allLine = "";
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: Could you please format your question, and add an actual question to it? The way it is now, there is no way for us to know what you want to ask.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form. 3) See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. ..

Comment: .. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Edited to the format , can you please help me in this?

Comment: @Stultuske Edited to the format , can you please look on to it

Comment: ***Wow!*** You've had time to go through the entire "When Runtime.exec() won't" document and implement all its recommendations in just 5 minutes?!? F'cken amazing. But now you need to [edit] the question to show an MCVE of the altered code. Of course, I expect to see *every* recommendation implemented in the MCVE.